# Can I use a parameter I get from another controller to the current initializable?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have two different controllers, but by getting a certain value at one of them I want to use it at the second controller's initializable.

This is the part where the first controller sends the **region** parameter to the other controler

```
    public void enterlevel(String x) throws IOException{

    FXMLLoader Loader=new FXMLLoader();

    Loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(x));

    Loader.load();

    regionalController reg=Loader.getController();
    reg.getRegion(region);


    //System.out.println(region);

    Parent root = Loader.getRoot();

    Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Ziga Ziga");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();


    Stage stage = (Stage) loginButton.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.close();

}
```

This is where the second controller gets it

```
    public void getRegion(String region) {
    System.out.println(region+" UO UO UO ");
    regi=region;
    }
```

And this is the initializable where I can't use the value as it starts

```
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {     
    System.out.println(regi);
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/bimbima","root","");  
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  `file` WHERE Region = '"+regi+"'");  
        while(rs.next())  {
        filename=rs.getString("filename");
        nameofSup=rs.getString("Name of Supervisor");
        System.out.println(filename);
        }
        con.close();  
        }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that `getRegion(...)` just stuck there because I was using it before for something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside: surely your `getRegion(...)` method should be called `setRegion(...)`, since it changes the value of a property, and doesn't return anything.

Just change the code in the second controller so that you only retrieve the values from the database when you know the region:

```
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {     
}

public void setRegion(String region) {
    regi=region;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/bimbima","root","");  
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  `file` WHERE Region = '"+regi+"'");  
        while(rs.next())  {
        filename=rs.getString("filename");
        nameofSup=rs.getString("Name of Supervisor");
        System.out.println(filename);
        }
        con.close();  
    } catch(Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
}
```